# VBA Word: Find immediate proceeding header

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with a lot of tables. I'd like to map each table to the immediate heading they are listed under. Right now I am thinking of passing through the selection cursor through each individual table and somehow find the immediate heading that the selection cursor is under. I am having trouble with finding the heading. I cannot find any documented member functions that can help me do this.

```
For Each T In wrdDoc.Tables
wrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=wdGoToNext
'Find heading
Next T
```

*edit*
To clarify the formatting of the document:

### 1

*Table 1*
*Table 2*

### 1.1

*Table 3*

### 1.1.1

*Table 4*

### 1.2

*Table 5*

### 2

### 2.1

*Table 6*

Basically, there are multiple levels of headings. Under each, there may or may not be multiple tables. So in the case above, I'd like to figure out a way to map Tables 1 and 2 to 1, Table 3 to 1.1, Table 4 to 1.1.1 and etc..

Comment: your question is unclear- what is where?, what you mean by immediate heading?, etc...? The best idea i have for you is to add screenshot or a scheme of your table with headings.

Comment: See http://word.mvps.org/faqs/numbering/liststring.htm  You would have to MoveLeft until you got to the 1st paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

If your heading are list paragraphs then you could use the following solution:

```
Sub Under_Table_Numbered_List_Item()

    Dim TBL As Table
    For Each TBL In ActiveDocument.Tables

        'get first list item below each table
        'select it- not required
        ActiveDocument.Range(TBL.Range.End).ListParagraphs(1).Range.Select

        'read its text
        Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Range(TBL.Range.End).ListParagraphs(1).Range.Text

    Next

End Sub
```

But if you want to find first heading below each table where heading is a style then try with this code:

```
Sub Under_Table_Heading_style()

    Dim TBL As Table
    Dim Para As Paragraph
    For Each TBL In ActiveDocument.Tables

        'get first heading below table
        'based on style name
        For Each Para In ActiveDocument.Range(TBL.Range.End).Paragraphs
            Para.Range.Select

            If Para.Range.Style = "Heading 1" Then
                    'this is your heading
                    Debug.Print Para.Range.Text
            End If

            'stop searchin if you reach next table
            If Para.Range.Tables.Count > 0 Then Exit For
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want (Word 2003).

```
Option Explicit

Sub DC1() ' find immediate preceeding header for all tables
  Dim tblnum&, swnone&
  For tblnum = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
    swnone = 0 ' to detect "before all numbered paragraphs"
    ActiveDocument.Tables(tblnum).Cell(1, 1).Select
    Do ' get out of table
      If Selection.MoveLeft(wdCharacter, 1) = 0 Then swnone = 1: Exit Do
    Loop While Selection.Information(wdWithInTable)
    Do ' find previous numbered paragraph
      If Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListParagraphs.Count = 1 Then Exit Do
      If Selection.MoveLeft(wdCharacter, 1) = 0 Then swnone = 1: Exit Do
    Loop
    If swnone Then
      Debug.Print "Tbl#" & tblnum, "Before first numbered paragraph"
    Else
      Debug.Print "Tbl#" & tblnum, Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString
    End If
  Next tblnum
End Sub
```